# hwo html, css, js integration in the browser actually works?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I'm a person who comes from algorithm and data structures background (in c++, c, Python, Java and etc.) and my only experience in frontend is Processing and p5.js. How browsers integrate html, css and js?
Do Javascript scripts generate a new .html file as page at certain framerate? How does it really work inside the browser? Or do most popular libraries like Angular make "syscalls" to the web browser to generate content?

Does using libraries like Angular etc. make generating new html "frame" documents somehow automated for dynamic pages?

I mean apart from all Javascript operations isn't the final displayed content a html file in the end?

Comment: Every major browser is built in C/C++ as well as JavaScript is written in C++ (and obviously as well, nodejs). So those environments (browsers and node) have not only built-in js support but also APIs added to use (logically you can't call the DOM on a nodejs environment, as well some APIs from node are not available via browsers). It's hard to explain this on a 500 characters text lol but I would simply suggest you check this video out if you haven't yet https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ it talks about a JavaScript feature and how it's related to the environment where is running.